# C# to VB.Net Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is equivalent for below code in VB.NET

```
new FormsAuthentication().SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, true, ticketData);
```

Ref : http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/04/04/released-formsauthenticationextensions

Comment: [Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were legal, the equivalent code in VB.NET would be the following (note the `Call` in the beginning -- that's the magical part that makes this work):

```
Call (New FormsAuthentication()).SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, true, ticketData)
```

Another option would be use`With`:

```
With New FormsAuthentication()
    .SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, true, ticketData)
End With
```

But as Darin has said, `SetAuthCookie()` is a static method and should be called as such.

Answer (score 3):

For starters [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd.aspx) is a static method, so you shouldn't be creating any instance of [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx). So the correct way to do this in C# is the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, true, ticketData);
```

and in VB.NET the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, True, ticketData)
```

Conclusion: almost the same. If you are following VB.NET conventions you would probably write `True` instead of `true` and get rid of the `;`.